# Cannot copy large activity between solutions

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, workflow-manager

I've been successfully using Visual Studio 2012 to copy/paste workflow activities between workflows in separate solutions. This has worked really great until I ran into an activity which is quite large - 43KB (Clipboard data is 43571 bytes long). I know that activity gets successfully copied because I can paste it in notepad and see that entire XML has been copied. But when I try to paste it in another workflow, "Paste" option in context menu is disabled:

[image: Paste disabled]

I am trying to avoid a situation where I need to copy activities partially. Does anyone have a suggestion how to workaround this issue?

**EDIT**: I can successfully copy activity which has clipboard data 36421 bytes long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I copied XML manually i.e. I opened the target workflow in code view (F7 key in Visual Studio) and I pasted the activity XML directly to *workflow.xaml* file.

**EDIT:**
There seems to be another solution to this. If target workflow is empty then drag one `WriteToHistory` activity to workflow surface and try to copy activities. Apparently dropping `WriteToHistory` activity (or any activity AFAIK) causes workflow XAML to add necessary dependencies. At the end simply delete `WriteToHistory` activity.